# name 'bins' is not defined (Wind rose)

Tags: python

I want to make wind rose. Here is my code :

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/dedy/Documents/windrose/TAOYUAN2006.csv')
data['Dir(Rounded)'] = (data['Dir(DegT)']/(360/16)).round().mod(16)*360/16
frequencies = pd.crosstab(data['Dir(Rounded)'], pd.cut(data['Speed(m/s)'], bins)) / data['Dir(Rounded)'].size
frequencies.to_csv('frequencies.csv', sep='\t')
```

This is the error I'm getting :

> NameError: name 'bins' is not defined

Comment: Reformat your code b highlighting and hitting Ctrl + K and better explanation to your problem.

Comment: Read this : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html

If you want to quickly understand, define bins above your code

Answer (score 0):

It's quite obvious what the error is ... you don't have `bins` specified.

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) are the docs for pandas' crosstab method.

Check [this](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/even-easier-frequency-tables-in-pandas-0-7-0/) out. Bins would be the *group* that each value fall under, something like a range.